# Run codeigniter script as root user

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to run a codeigniter  function as root user. I am trying to change the owner and group of folder using php chown function. But it doesnt working at all. Is there any way which I can change the folder user and group from apache(user) to myusername ?

Comment: Login as root and run it.

Comment: I need to run it trough webpage

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing it. Either run Apache as root (completely unsafe) or use the php system function to run chown using sudo.

Assuming you are using chown function as in the example below:

```
<?php
$path='/path/to/filename'
$username = 'myuser'
chown($path, $username)
?>
```

Replace with

```
<?php
$path='/path/to/filename'
$username = 'myuser'
system('sudo chown '.$username.' '.$path)
?>
```

You need to adjust the /etc/sudoers file to allow the apache user to run the chown command without password.

Or you can

```
chown root ./phpscript.php
chmod +s ./phpscript.php
```

The script will always run as root. Read more about chmod +s

Comment: please give me more details

Comment: Assuming you are using chown function as in the example below:
<?php
$path='/path/to/filename'
$username = 'myuser'
chown($path, $username)
?>
Replace with
<?php
$path='/path/to/filename'
$username = 'myuser'
system('sudo chown '.$username.' '.$path)
?>

You need to adjust the /etc/sudoers file to allow the apache user to run the chown command without password.

Comment: Another way is to chmod the script with +s and chown it to root. Then it will always run as root.